# Show $d_1(x, y) = |x-y|, d_2(x, y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ not strongly equivalent on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to show $d_1(x, y) = |x-y|$ and $d_2(x, y) = \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|}$ are not strongly equivalent metrics on $\mathbb{R}$.

i.e. That there exist no $c_1, c_2 > 0$ such that for all $x, y \in X$,

$$c_1|x-y| \leq \frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|} \leq c_2|x-y|$$

Is there an example in $\mathbb{R}$ that shows they are not strongly equivalent?

Comment: Can you remind us of the definition of strongly equivalent.

Comment: Choose $y = 0$ and make $x > 0$ laaaarge ... (and note that $c_1, c_2$ must be *independent* of $x, y$)

Comment: You can find $c_2>0$. Actually, $c_2=1$ is ok. But you won't find $c_1>0$, because of Martin R's advice. Otherwise said, that inequality only holds if $c_1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $$d_2(x, y) \leq 1$$

If they would be strongly equivalent $d_1$ would be bounded.